# Paperclip install issues with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Installed plugin, then ran bundle install and get this...

```
bundle install
Updating git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rails3': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
Git error: command `git rev-parse rails3` in directory /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/paperclip-61f74de14812cabc026967a2b2c3ca8cbd2eed69'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your gemfile is pointing the paperclip revision to `rails3`. This is no longer necessary, as the gem is caught up with the current version of Rails.

Comment: No problem! With 90% of Rails issues it's always something like that. :)